# Is there a specific encounter in Star Wars media where Darth Vader tricks or bamboozles an opponent with the dual-phase feature of his lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, lightsaber

There is a page on [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dual-phase_lightsaber#cite_note-GaG-3) that explains the nature of the Dual-phase lightsaber and how it can be used to destabilize opponents. It cites works where the weapons appears, but it seems to be just a list of Darth Vader appearances which would be impractical to sort through.

The lightsaber is itself described in an [RPG sourcebook](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gadgets_and_Gear) as a type of saber whose length can be adjusted during combat due to having more than one kyber crystal installed.

Is there an actual occurrence in Star Wars where Darth Vader (or any other character for that matter) prevails over an opponent using lightsaber beam length changes?

Comment: If memory serves, they added the whole "dual phase" nonsense to explain why the length of the blade is so inconsistent in the original films

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that the validity of the RPG sourcebooks is dubious at best. They tend to freely borrow from EU material quite often, which yes, is where the idea of "duel phase" comes from. In 'Rebels', Kanan's saber just has a control to manually adjust the blade length to suit the wielder, which makes much more sense given a Jedi typically builds their sabre when they're still initiates and thus not fully grown adult. Moreover, Vader really doesn't need to use cheap tricks. He usually goes for the most direct, brutal tactics.

Comment: In the old EU Corran Horn uses a duel phase saber, and IIRC uses it to trick enemies - see eg the second Yuuzhan Bong book